# Flutter firebase messaging push notification format 3 lines

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am working on firebase push notification for my project. I am receiving notification on all my devices.

My problem is **iOS devices showing notifications in below format.**

```
Title  :
Subtitle :
text/body:
```

**My android devices showing notifications in below format.**

```
Title :
text/body:
```

below is the payload i am using for sending notification.

```
 var payload = {   "notification":{
          "title":"New Price Alert! "+ clientDataAfter.productname,
"subtitle":"Get before its gone",
          "body":"Old Price "+clientDataAfter.oldprice+" || New Price "+ clientDataAfter.newprice,
          "click_action":"FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
        "data" : {
          "id":ID,
          "name": Name,
          "newprice":newprice
        }, }
```

I want to show notifications in 3 line format on both iOS and android. 
How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello .. Awaiting for answer...

Answer (score 0):

Add "subtitle" to "data" with "id", "name", ...